# php login form hiding the rest of the site

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add a login form onto my free mathhelp site, but whenever i include the form in my index page, it is hiding the rest of the site. Here is the source code all credit to Codex-m:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

//require user configuration and database connection parameters
require('config.php');

if (($_SESSION['logged_in'])==TRUE) {
//valid user has logged-in to the website

//Check for unauthorized use of user sessions

$iprecreate= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$useragentrecreate=$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$signaturerecreate=$_SESSION['signature'];

//Extract original salt from authorized signature

$saltrecreate = substr($signaturerecreate, 0, $length_salt);

//Extract original hash from authorized signature

$originalhash = substr($signaturerecreate, $length_salt, 40);

//Re-create the hash based on the user IP and user agent
//then check if it is authorized or not

$hashrecreate= sha1($saltrecreate.$iprecreate.$useragentrecreate);

if (!($hashrecreate==$originalhash)) {

//Signature submitted by the user does not matched with the
//authorized signature
//This is unauthorized access
//Block it

header(sprintf("Location: %s", $forbidden_url));    
exit;    
}

//Session Lifetime control for inactivity
//Credits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

if ((isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $sessiontimeout)))  {

session_destroy();   
session_unset();  

//redirect the user back to login page for re-authentication

$redirectback=$domain.'securelogin/';
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $redirectback));
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); 

}

//Pre-define validation
$validationresults=TRUE;
$registered=TRUE;
$recaptchavalidation=TRUE;

//Trapped brute force attackers and give them more hard work by providing a captcha-protected page

$iptocheck= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$iptocheck= mysql_real_escape_string($iptocheck);

if ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT `loggedip` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`='$iptocheck'"))) {

//Already has some IP address records in the database
//Get the total failed login attempts associated with this IP address

$resultx = mysql_query("SELECT `failedattempts` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`='$iptocheck'");
$rowx = mysql_fetch_array($resultx);
$loginattempts_total = $rowx['failedattempts'];

If ($loginattempts_total>$maxfailedattempt) {

//too many failed attempts allowed, redirect and give 403 forbidden.

header(sprintf("Location: %s", $forbidden_url));    
exit;
}
}

//Check if a user has logged-in

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = FALSE;
}

//Check if the form is submitted

if ((isset($_POST["pass"])) && (isset($_POST["user"])) && ($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']==FALSE)) {

//Username and password has been submitted by the user
//Receive and sanitize the submitted information

function sanitize($data){
$data=trim($data);
$data=htmlspecialchars($data);
$data=mysql_real_escape_string($data);
return $data;
}

$user=sanitize($_POST["user"]);
$pass= sanitize($_POST["pass"]);

//validate username
if (!($fetch = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `authentication` WHERE `username`='$user'")))) {

//no records of username in database
//user is not yet registered

$registered=FALSE;
}

if ($registered==TRUE) {

//Grab login attempts from MySQL database for a corresponding username
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `loginattempt` FROM `authentication` WHERE `username`='$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$loginattempts_username = $row['loginattempt'];

}

if(($loginattempts_username>2) || ($registered==FALSE) || ($loginattempts_total>2)) {

//Require those user with login attempts failed records to 
//submit captcha and validate recaptcha

require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

//captcha validation fails

$recaptchavalidation=FALSE;
} else {
$recaptchavalidation=TRUE;  
}
}

//Get correct hashed password based on given username stored in MySQL database

if ($registered==TRUE) {

//username is registered in database, now get the hashed password

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `authentication` WHERE `username`='$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$correctpassword = $row['password'];
$salt = substr($correctpassword, 0, 64);
$correcthash = substr($correctpassword, 64, 64);
$userhash = hash("sha256", $salt . $pass);
}
if ((!($userhash == $correcthash)) || ($registered==FALSE) || ($recaptchavalidation==FALSE)) {

//user login validation fails

$validationresults=FALSE;

//log login failed attempts to database

if ($registered==TRUE) {
$loginattempts_username= $loginattempts_username + 1;
$loginattempts_username=intval($loginattempts_username);

//update login attempt records

mysql_query("UPDATE `authentication` SET `loginattempt` = '$loginattempts_username' WHERE `username` = '$user'");

//Possible brute force attacker is targeting registered usernames
//check if has some IP address records

if (!($fetch = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT `loggedip` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`='$iptocheck'")))) {

//no records
//insert failed attempts

$loginattempts_total=1;
$loginattempts_total=intval($loginattempts_total);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ipcheck` (`loggedip`, `failedattempts`) VALUES ('$iptocheck', '$loginattempts_total')");  
} else {

//has some records, increment attempts

$loginattempts_total= $loginattempts_total + 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE `ipcheck` SET `failedattempts` = '$loginattempts_total' WHERE `loggedip` = '$iptocheck'");
}
}

//Possible brute force attacker is targeting randomly

if ($registered==FALSE) {
if (!($fetch = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT `loggedip` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`='$iptocheck'")))) {

//no records
//insert failed attempts

$loginattempts_total=1;
$loginattempts_total=intval($loginattempts_total);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ipcheck` (`loggedip`, `failedattempts`) VALUES ('$iptocheck', '$loginattempts_total')");  
} else {

//has some records, increment attempts

$loginattempts_total= $loginattempts_total + 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE `ipcheck` SET `failedattempts` = '$loginattempts_total' WHERE `loggedip` = '$iptocheck'");
}
}
} else {

//user successfully authenticates with the provided username and password

//Reset login attempts for a specific username to 0 as well as the ip address

$loginattempts_username=0;
$loginattempts_total=0;
$loginattempts_username=intval($loginattempts_username);
$loginattempts_total=intval($loginattempts_total);
mysql_query("UPDATE `authentication` SET `loginattempt` = '$loginattempts_username' WHERE `username` = '$user'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `ipcheck` SET `failedattempts` = '$loginattempts_total' WHERE `loggedip` = '$iptocheck'");

//Generate unique signature of the user based on IP address
//and the browser then append it to session
//This will be used to authenticate the user session 
//To make sure it belongs to an authorized user and not to anyone else.
//generate random salt
function genRandomString() {
//credits: http://bit.ly/a9rDYd
    $length = 50;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdef";      
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length ; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
$random=genRandomString();
$salt_ip= substr($random, 0, $length_salt);

//hash the ip address, user-agent and the salt
$useragent=$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$hash_user= sha1($salt_ip.$iptocheck.$useragent);

//concatenate the salt and the hash to form a signature
$signature= $salt_ip.$hash_user;

//Regenerate session id prior to setting any session variable
//to mitigate session fixation attacks

session_regenerate_id();

//Finally store user unique signature in the session
//and set logged_in to TRUE as well as start activity time

$_SESSION['signature'] = $signature;
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); 
}
} 

if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']): 

?>

<!-- START OF LOGIN FORM -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
Username:  <input type="text" class="<?php if ($validationresults==FALSE) echo "invalid"; ?>" id="user" name="user">
Password: <input name="pass" type="password" class="<?php if ($validationresults==FALSE) echo "invalid"; ?>" id="pass" >
<?php if (($loginattempts_username > 5) || ($registered==FALSE) || ($loginattempts_total> 5)) { ?>
Type the captcha below:
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($validationresults==FALSE) echo '<font color="red">Please enter valid username, password or captcha (if required).</font>'; ?>
<input type="submit" value="Login">                   
</form>
<!-- END OF LOGIN FORM -->
<a href="register.php">Register</a>.
<?php
exit();
endif;
?>
```

what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fptqm.jpg, what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y63GT.jpg (this is only after the user logs in., it should look like this before the user logs in with the login thing up the top) Basically it is hiding all the code underneath the login once it is embeded
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `exit();` on the third to last line is causing the page to stop being printed out past that point. Remove that line to fix your problem.